# when used .remove function of mutable List compiler throws exception any alternative?

Tags: kotlin, exception, mutablelist

This gives Exception in thread "main":

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: remove

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   val list = listOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
   var record: MutableList<Int>;
   record = list as MutableList<Int>;
   record.remove(2);
   print(record);
}
```

Comment: There's a difference between a `List` and `MutableList`. Also, this isn't Java. Semicolons aren't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Casting does not change an object into a different kind of object. When you assign `list` to `record`, it is still a read-only `List`, but you've forced the compiler to treat it like a `MutableList`, so it will fail at runtime instead of compile time.

Since you instantiate `list` as a read-only `List`, it is protected from changes (at least to its size). If that is not what you want, you should instantiate it as a `MutableList` to begin with. Or if you just need a copy of it that you can change, you can use `toMutableList()` to get a copy.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [.toMutableList()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-mutable-list.html) to copy the list in a new mutable list:

```
val list = listOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
val record = list.toMutableList()
record.remove(2)
print(record)
```

This outputs:

```
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: to clarify, it copies original list in a new mutable list. Operations with `record` will not affect `list`